# How to properly implement dynamic imports with React.lazy in a React TypeScript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, configuration

I'm building a React TypeScript application and trying to implement dynamic imports to lazy-load some components for better performance. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to use the dynamic import statement:

```
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
```

Here's an example of my current implementation:
App.tsx

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react- router-dom';

const MyComponent = lazy(() => import('./MyComponent'));

const App: FC = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/mycomponent" component={MyComponent} />
                    {/* other routes */}
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </Router>
     );
  };

  export default App;
```

MyComponent.tsx

```
const MyComponent: FC = () => {
  return <div>Hello, I'm MyComponent!</div>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

My project is set up using Create React App with the following dependencies and TypeScript configuration:

package.json (relevant parts)

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json (relevant parts)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I've tried a few different solutions I found online, but none of them seem to be working. Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution? How can I properly implement dynamic imports in a React TypeScript project?

Comment: I'm not seeing any syntax issue with the line of code you provided.  Can you include more of the code?  Preferably you would show just enough code for us to reproduce the error.

Comment: Edited question, sorry for unclean context